# vb.net ISCP receiving after sending

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient, streamwriter, networkstream

Hey all i have the following code that i send a command over the network to a Onkyo A/V reciever. I would like to get the feedback from that as well but i can not seem to find a way of doing that. I know the command to send to have it send something back but as for the code below, it only sends out a command and doesnt listen for a return. That is what i am in need of help with doing:

```
Private Sub SendCommand(ByVal command As String)
    Dim Stream As NetworkStream
    Dim Client As New TcpClient()
    Dim streamw As StreamWriter
    Dim i As Int32

    Client.Connect("192.168.9.100", 60128)
    Stream = Client.GetStream()

    If Client.Connected And Stream.CanWrite Then
        streamw = New StreamWriter(Stream)
        Dim sendBytes(command.Length + 18) As Char

        sendBytes(0) = "I"
        sendBytes(1) = "S"
        sendBytes(2) = "C"
        sendBytes(3) = "P"
        sendBytes(4) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(5) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(6) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(7) = Chr(16)
        sendBytes(8) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(9) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(10) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(11) = Chr(command.Length + 3)
        sendBytes(12) = Chr(1)
        sendBytes(13) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(14) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(15) = Chr(0)
        sendBytes(16) = "!"
        sendBytes(17) = "1"

        For i = 0 To (command.Length - 1)
            sendBytes(18 + i) = command.Chars(i)
        Next

        sendBytes(command.Length + 18) = Chr(13) '&HD
        streamw.Write(sendBytes)

        'Dim bytes(Client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        'Stream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(Client.ReceiveBufferSize))
        'Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
        'Debug.Print(("Host returned: " + returndata))

        streamw.Flush()
    Else
        MsgBox("error: Stream writing failed")
    End If
    Client.Close()
End Sub
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

David